# What's the proper way to access a Swift Package item from Objective-C?

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift-package-manager, swift-package

**Scenario:**
I had built a Swift <-- package simple App that is working. 
Now I'm trying to convert this to a Objective-C <--- package app.

**Question #1:** How to I formally import the package? 
I've read to use the '@import' vs the older '#import'.

Now I'm getting the "'init'isn't available".

[image]

Here's the package ("RicPackage.swift"):

```
import Foundation

public struct RicStruct {
    public private(set) var text = "Hello, World!"

    public init() {
    }
    
    public func sayHello() -> String {
        "Hello Ric!"
    }
}

public class RicClass: NSObject {
    @objc public var msg = "Mother has a feeling, I might be too appealing."
    @objc public let text = "Hello Everybody!"
    
    
    public init(msg: String) {
        if msg.isEmpty {
            self.msg = "Hello Ric!"
        }
    }
  
    public func sayHello() {
            print(text)
        }
    
    public func doSomething() {
        print("Inside doSomething()")
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to a least do something simple like:

```
RicClass *ricClass = [[RicClass alloc] init];
[ricClass sayHello];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see init() in your Swift class, if you are trying to call `[[RicClass alloc] init]` add init in your swift class:

```
 public override init() {
        
    }
```

You can only call `initWithMsg` for now with your current swift class:

```
[[RicClass alloc] initWithMsg:@""]
```