# Objective-C accessing Swift Package functions

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swift-package

**Goal:** To use Swift Package within Objective-C.

All I'm trying to do is to have a simple, rudimentary understanding of the correct syntax of access Swift vars & func() from ObjC.

This is the second part of questions about [using Objective-C with a Swift package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597786/whats-the-proper-way-to-access-a-swift-package-item-from-objective-c).

[image]

Here's my Swift Package file that I'm trying to access... 
I'm concentrating on the Swift **class** access. 
But I would also like to know how to access the **struct**.

```
import Foundation

public struct RicStruct {
    public private(set) var text = "Hello, World!"

    public init() {
    }
    
    public func sayHello() -> String {
        "Hello Ric!"
    }
}

public class RicClass: NSObject {
    @objc public var msg = "Mother has a feeling, I might be too appealing."
    @objc public let text = "Hello Everybody!"
    
    public override init() {}
    
    public func sayHello() {
            print(text)
        }
    
    public func doSomething() {
        print("Inside doSomething()")
    }
}
```

This is the Objective-C parent attempting to access the Swift-Package vars & func:

[image]

**Question:** What's the proper syntax of accessing:

1. the Swift class & struct functions,
2. the Swift var/let?

Comment: Swift structs cannot be accessed from Objective-C. You need to convert them to classes, or create a bridging class. Classes must be marked with `@objc`. And in Obj C `....m` file, you need to `#import <Module/Module-Swift.h>`

Comment: Good to know.  Accessing Swift struct is purely academic, not needed.

Comment: have a look at this useless project that does some in and out to swift, from swift, calling cpp, objC etc.. its a mess but it shows what is needed..
in particular all in this folder
https://github.com/designerfuzzi/CombineCppSwiftObjcInStaticLib/tree/main/CombineCppSwiftObjcInStaticLib/Hub_lib

Comment: Have you tried to use Xcode's autocompletion? It might suggest something and if it doesn't, then something's wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I've tried autocompletion which didn't show anything.  Hence the query.  I'm trying to create an elementary ObjC->Swift Package scenario for posterity/reference.

Comment: Also generally, I suggest to just follow apple's guide here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared

```
public func sayHello() {
    print(text)
}
```

That makes the method `sayHello` public across module, but it does not expose it to Objective-C. Instead:

```
@objc public func sayHello() {
    print(text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't add the '@objc' qualifier to the Swift function. 
 I had mistakenly thought that it's not necessary due to being a member of a NSObject class per class declaration.

Also, didn't need to add the .h ObjC <--> Swift bridge file.

[image]

Comment: not wrong, depending on your project. But matt's solution is more simple.
`@objc`exists not only to expose it, it is used to have fine control what is exposed and how the exposed method should be named to avoid clashes

Comment: and the tricky part is that exposing objC->swift generates an IDE visible file named projectnameBridging-Header.h to control it, but the other way exposing swift->objc is an "virtual" autogenerated h.file from your @objc marks that has to be imported on the objc side or objc++ side

Comment: like here https://github.com/designerfuzzi/CombineCppSwiftObjcInStaticLib/blob/a653d401a20346b01c5dbd23a8e252df1abb2ff4/CombineCppSwiftObjcInStaticLib/Hub_lib/Hub_lib.mm#L12
this file does actually not exist, it is autogenerated and is only working because of the @objc marks